# when i submit empty date i got error like this String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

here my code  is

```
string DateOfBirth;
```

manageusers.DateOfBirth1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfBirth);

default it will display like this

```
manageusers.DateOfBirth1 = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make DateOfBirth1 a nullable property like this:

```
public DateTime? DateOfBirth1 { get; set; }
```

A better solution is to do something like this:

```
DateOfBirth1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateOfBirth) 
           ? (DateTime?) null 
           : DateTime.Parse(DateOfBirth);
```

Comment: i got error  when run above code......

Comment: parse cannot convert null